# What are the implications of using an inode_ratio of 16384 in terms of storage use on ext4?

Tags: ext4, storage, inode

I'm assuming that this means that if the average file stored (including directories etc) is less than 16384 bytes, it may be possible to run out of inodes before using the full storage capacity of the filesystem. However, should the files being stored consume over 16384 bytes, on average, a physical space storage limit should be reached before one would run out of inodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is about right. A couple of minor points to note are:

1. As far as I can see the overhead of the filsystem itself isn't considered when calculating the number of inodes from this ratio, so the actual average size that a file can be will be slightly lower than 16834 when you consider the overhead superblock, inode table etc. Each inode itself is 256 bytes by default on `ext4`. So if this ratio is very low, the size of the inodes themselves is substantial.
2. Symlinks also count as inodes, so remember that a large number will bring down the average file size.
3. 16834 is the default inode_ratio on Linux and should suit most needs. Only change it if you have a good reason to. There are other values defined in `/etc/mke2fs.conf` for specific usage types. Consider if one of these suits your needs (specify it with the `-T` option to `mkfs.ext4`) before defining your own.

Comment: Yes, I was concerned the default might have been wasteful for our typical file sizes in our documents and image store but it turns out it is reasonable for our files mostly ranging from 200KB-500KB in size.